# Ansible returning "no action detected in task"

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I'm running `ansible-playbook` version 2.7.6+dfsg-1 on Debian Buster. I have a playbook that includes another, like so:

```
---
- hosts: "{{ target }}"
  tasks:
  - include_tasks: set-timezone.yaml
```

The contents of the included `set-timezone.yaml` is as follows:

```
---
- hosts: all
  tasks:
  - name: set timezone to MST
    timezone:
      name: America/Denver
```

When I run the playbook, I get an error telling me this:

```
no action detected in task. This often indicates a misspelled module name, or incorrect module path.
The error appears to have been in '/etc/ansible/playbooks/set-timezone.yaml': line 2, column 3, but maybe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.
The offending line appears to be:
---
- hosts: all
  ^ here
```

I saw a similar question in which the asker mispelled the name of the module, but I'm quite sure "timezone" is spelled correctly and this module is in 2.7 as per the [official docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/timezone_module.html). I tried removing `hosts: all` from `set-timezone.yaml` and got this error instead: "included task files must contain a list of tasks".

Comment: Can you try running the tasks by deleting the hosts and tasks line from the included play i.e from set-timezone.yaml

Comment: Yep, that did the trick. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> and got this error instead: "included task files must contain a list of tasks".

Correct, the "list of tasks" part means exactly that: a yaml list made up of items that are themselves ansible tasks:

```
# cat set-timezone.yaml
---
- name: this is a task
  debug: msg="hello, world"
- name: set timezone to MST
  timezone:
    name: America/Denver
```

Comment: Thanks, that solved things! I didn't realize you need to remove the ```hosts``` and ```tasks``` lines.